# how to pick a number in a text file and multiply it

Tags: python, file

I'm quite new to python and I'm struggling to solve a problem, I have a text file with the name of the items and the price beside it, I'm tasked to multiply the price in the text file to a number in a variable or user input, for example, the user input 3, I need to multiply it to the price of the water and print it. how to do it? please help me.

this is the content of the text file

[content of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yix9.png)

this is what I've done so far I've managed to print all the numbers but I don't know to choose only one number

```
with open("prac.txt") as r:
for line in r:
    if line:
        print(line.split(' ')[1])
```

this prints out
3
4
2
6
7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
price=[]
item=[]
with open("textfile.txt") as r:
 for line in r:
   if line:
        price.extend(line.split(' $')[1])
        item.append(line.split(' $')[0])
price=list(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', price))

a=dict(zip(item,price))
```

now you have a dictionary with key as item names and you can access and multiply whatever prices you want, eg- for multiplying water price by 3 you can do:

```
print(int(a.get('water'))*3)
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot ,  this solve my problem